# Amazon Instance Ec2 Connection Timeout

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am using Amazon EC2 services &  and its working correctly but suddenly from 3-days before  when we try to access our instance using ssh connection we got following error:

> "ssh: connect to host ec2-**-**--***.compute-1.amazonaws.com port **: Connection timed out"

when I try to access our sites deployed on our EC2 instance, I received the same error ,

> "The connection has timed out
>   The server at ec2-**-**--***.compute-1.amazonaws.com is taking too long to respond"

there is no problem in network connection from our side as we are able to access other web site and services smoothly.

I can't even able to access hosted site without this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same problem.

I followed the troubleshooting in http://alestic.com/2010/05/ec2-move-ebs-boot-instance
Then when I tried to start a new instance, I got an message from Amazon:

Server.InsufficientInstanceCapacity: We currently do not have sufficient m1.small capacity in the Availability Zone you requested (us-east-1b). Our system will be working on provisioning additional capacity. You can currently get m1.small capacity by not specifying an Availability Zone in your request or choosing us-east-1d, us-east-1c, us-east-1a.

Maybe, you have an instance is us-east-1b, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access the System Console (either via the amazon web console or elasticfox) and check for any errors/messages that might help you arrive at the cause of this.

Answer (score 0):

In `~/.ssh/config`, add the following lines:

```sh
ServerAliveInterval 50
```

This will keep on pinging the server every 50 seconds to keep the connection alive.